# when doing git push, it creates pull request on repository using another account

Tags: git

I am using git terminal on visual studio code and I have tried to push recent changes to remote repository but it happens to create `pull request` on the repository using another account. (eg. after `git push`, User2 creates pull request on User1's repo even though my global email is same as User1's email.) I have deleted all git credential from windows credential manager and I have set the global email to User1's email address but it still creates pull request from User2.

Anyone knows why it is happening ?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're doing anything "wrong", or there's a problem with your VSCode configuration: 1) Your remote is on Github (or Azure DevOps), correct?  2) Your GitHub repo is probably  configured so that "push" results in a "pull request": https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/pushing-commits-to-a-remote-repository

Comment: yes, it seems like a settings issue in your repo where there might have been hooks created to create a pull request for incoming commits. So check on github for any such hooks.

Comment: Thanks a lot but I am still facing the same issue with Android Studio also. Even all global username and email are set to the same user, it push with different user email. I don't see anything wrong on my GitHub repo.